# Setup project for .Net core application

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, windows-installer

Trying to add a setup project for .NET core application through Visual studio installer.

It is not able to detect the dependencies and while trying to build, Visual studio crashes.

But it is working for normal .NET applications.

How to create setup project for .NET core application?